# question on code snippet useEffect with fetching state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am reading this code snipper https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks linked from react documentation page https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks

I don't understand this piece of code with the returned function that modifies the ignore variable

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await axios('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query);
      if (!ignore) setData(result.data);
    }

    fetchData();
    return () => { ignore = true; }
  }, [query]);
```

once the function that is passed to useEffect is called a second time, doesn't ignore reset back to false leaving the ignore = true completely useless.  The code above does not compute for me.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: more info on clean up func [here](https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm)

Answer (score 0):

If an effect returns a cleanup function, React invokes it when the component unmounts or before the effect gets re-run due to a dependency change (if `query` were to change in this case).

The axios fetch call is asynchronous, so it's possible that the component will unmount or a dependency (e.g. query) will have changed before the data request completes.

If that happens, the returned function will have set ignore to true and the `fetchData` function won't try to call `setData` on the unmounted component. (Attempting to update state on an unmounted component causes an error.)

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup):

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Due to the way [javascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) work, the cleanup function can access the `ignore` variable in the enclosing scope.

***When the effect runs again, a *new* ignore variable gets declared with a new cleanup function that references the new variable.***

Answer (score 0):

The `ignored` variable is in function scope, current effect's `ignored` will be a different instance with the one in the next effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the functional call and variable assignment is correct, but you forgot the power of the async call :)

useEffect is called whenever it is needed (e.g. componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate by query keyword), so we roughly have

1. ignore = false
2. function fetchData is now defined
3. function fetchData is called

> keep the reset of useEffect in your mind for a sec.

let's say something happens which causes a re-render e.g. prop-change (but other than query) or even call that setData with newly fetched data.

your useEffect will affect nothing, cause query shallow-comparison can not find a change with the previous one. So the purpose of the ignore is not involved in this case, cause it is not going to change at all.

Also if the query change in any way the function execution would roughly (ignoring event loop, macro task everything for the moment) be something like:

```js
// ignore is false and for some reason query changes...

(() => { ignore = true })() // ignore = true
// continue running useEffect again.
// lets think nothing else will happend in gap
ignore = false // ignore = false
```

The only possible scenario I can think about is when your component is going to be unmounted when your useEffect fallback is being called. So here is when that async keyword wants its dignity back ️.

> Remember: The async function is not return anything by your command.
> Imagine the data arrive when your component is fully removed from the DOM, here is the role which that `ignore=true` plays in this useEffect.

**Preventing setData on unmounted component**